# Trying to get factions to arrange in segments? NetLogo code advice

Tags: netlogo

I've made a model that aranges factions (turtles in different colours) in a circle.

At the moment they arrange randomly, was wondering if someone could help me arrange them so, for example, red occupies the first 90 degrees, blue the next 90 degrees, etc (on setup).

Here's my code...

```
ask patch 0 0
[ ask patches in-radius ( max-pxcor * .9) with [  random-float 100 < density ]
  [ sprout 1
    [ set breed cons
      set shape "circle" 
      set faction random factions
      set heading random 360
      set size 1
    ]
  ]
]
```

.. guessing I will have to do 360 / fractions, but not sure how to phrase it, if someone could help me out that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The NetLogo primitive that's the closest to what you want to do is `in-cone`, which reports the set of turtles that are in the "cone of vision" of another turtle. But your "pie slices" should just be relative to `patch 0 0`, not to another turtle! No problem: just make a temporary turtle at `patch 0 0`, use it to get turtles `in-cone` with the appropriate angle, and kill your temporary turtle.

The following procedure can be used "as is" with your code (just call it from your `setup` procedure after creating your turtles exactly as you were doing before):

```
to assign-factions
  let angle 360 / factions
  foreach n-values factions [?] [
    ask patch 0 0 [ 
      sprout 1 [
        set heading ? * angle
        ask turtles in-cone max-pxcor angle [ set faction ? + 1 ]
        die
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

The code is pretty straightforward, except for maybe the more obscure `n-values`. You could replace it with a `while` loop if you prefer, but it's really just counting from `0` to `factions`.

Here is what you'd get with 5 factions:

[image: factions]